# Docker Image - Error with apt get update -y

Tags: docker

I am getting the following error while building an image

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  8.724MB
Step 1/2 : FROM bde2020/spark-worker:2.4.5-hadoop2.7
 ---> ddb1ab6d9850
Step 2/2 : RUN apt-get update -y
 ---> Running in 99bbfdabe226
/bin/sh: apt-get: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update -y' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Here is the docker file

```
FROM bde2020/spark-worker:2.4.5-hadoop2.7
RUN apt-get update -y
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base OS of that image is Alpine linux. You can verify yourself:

```
$ docker run --rm -it --entrypoint=cat bde2020/spark-worker:2.4.5-hadoop2.7 /etc/*-release
NAME="Alpine Linux"
ID=alpine
VERSION_ID=3.10.4
PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.10"
HOME_URL="https://alpinelinux.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/"
cat: can't open '/etc/system-release': No such file or directory
```

so instead of `apt`, you want to use `apk`.